# Swift Core Data : fetchBatchSize vs fetchOffset

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm new to ios swift programming. I have a large working set of data in my application (Core data) and i want to restrict it. I came across two options fetchBatchSize and fetchOffset.

In official documentation both offers same use

> fetchBatchSize
>   You can use this feature to restrict the working set of data in your
>   application. In combination with fetchLimit, you can create a subrange
>   of an arbitrary result set.
>
> fetchOffset This property can be used to restrict the working set of
>   data. In combination with fetchLimit, you can create a subrange of an
>   arbitrary result set.

Whats the differences between two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets say you have following objects in Core Data - A, B, C, D, E, F, G

If you try to fetch all objects you get `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]`

If you set an `fetchOffset` of 2 you will get [C, D, E, F, G], so it will fetch everything after the specified `fetchOffset`.

`fetchBatchSize` is used so that Core Data does not fetch all objects at once, lets say in this example you set `fetchBatchSize` to 2, it would fetch first two objects, so `A and B` and rest would be faults, when you would try to access C core data would fulfil the fault and get `C and D` as well.

Lets say you have 1000 names, and you list them in a `UITableView` you can only show 20 names at a time, it makes sense to set `fetchBatchSize` to a bit higher value than screenful of names, so if user never scrolls `Core Data` only fetched first 30 objects for example, as soon as user scrolls down `Core Data` will fetch in next 30 and next 30 objets...

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. One more doubt, i can achieve what fetchBatchSize does using fetchOffset and fetchLimit (By increasing the offset progressively from zero ). What is the performance difference? Which is better to use suppose if i have around 1 lakh data ?

Comment: I suppose you could achieve the same with `fetchOffset` and `fetchLimit` BUT you would be the one that would have to do `performFetch` call yourself if user wanted more data, with `fetchBatchSize` you get all the data back and you call `performFetch` just once, and CoreData under the hood faults in missing objects from SQL store as they are needed, so I would say that is a huge difference, one you have to do all the work, second CoreData does it for you...so second one wins ;)